# How to use Fread and Fwrite when i don't know the amount of data in a binary file

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I know the theory of `fwrite` and `fread` but I must be making some mistake because I can't make them work. I made a random struct, initialized an array and used `fwrite` to save it into a binary file. Then I opened the same binary file, used `fread` and saved what was inside in another array. With the debugger I saw what was inside the second array and it says, for example:

```
ParkingLot2[0].company= "ffffffffffffffff"
ParkingLot2[0].years=-842150451.
```

When pasting the code I removed all the stuff that made the code too long like `if (f==NULL)` for controlling the opening of the file and the `pointer==NULL` after the mallocs and the control that `fread` and `fwrite` read the right amount of data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct Cars {
    int years;
    char company[16];
}Tcars;

void WriteBinaryFile(char* file_name, Tcars* p_1)
{
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(file_name, "wb");
    fwrite(p_1, sizeof(Tcars), 3, f);
    fclose(f);
    return;
}

Tcars* ReadBinaryFile(char* file_name, Tcars* p_2, int* pc)
{
    FILE* f;
    Tcars temp;
    size_t number = 1;
    f = fopen("cars.dat", "rb");
        while (number) {
            number = fread(&temp, sizeof(Tcars), 1, f);
            if (number)
                (*pc)++;
        }
/*i already know that the size is 3 but i want to try this method because in my last exam i
 was given a .dat file from my professor and i didn't know how much data i had to read through */
        if ((*pc) != 0)
        {
            p_2 = malloc(sizeof(Tcars) * (*pc));
            fread(p_2, sizeof(Tcars), (*pc), f);
        }
        fclose(f);
    return p_2;
}

int main()
{
    Tcars* ParkingLot1 = malloc(sizeof(Tcars) * 3);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        ParkingLot1[i].years = 2000 + i;
    }
    strcpy(ParkingLot1[0].company, "Fiat");
    strcpy(ParkingLot1[1].company, "Ford");
    strcpy(ParkingLot1[2].company,"Toyota");
    Tcars* ParkingLot2 = NULL;
    int cars_amount = 0;
    WriteBinaryFile("cars.dat", ParkingLot1);
    ParkingLot2 = ReadBinaryFile("cars.dat", ParkingLot2, &cars_amount);
    free(ParkingLot1);
    free(ParkingLot2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does the file pointer point to after you've read the whole file to count the number of entries? You need to use `fseek` or `rewind` to move the pointer back to the beginning of the file before trying to read the data. You should also always check for a valid file pointer before using or closing it.

Comment: What actually is the question here? Is it "how should I know, when I read the file, how many cars there are?" Is it a debugging request? Something else? If it is a debugging request, please try to think carefully about the logic of the code. After the `while (number) {` loop, where is the file pointer? Therefore, what will happen the next time you attempt to `fread`?

Comment: See [man 3 fread - RETURN VALUE](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) You need to validate the return and check `feof()` and `ferror()` to identify when `EOF` is reached or error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of small (and some not so small errors) that are causing you problems. Your primary problem is passing `Tcars* p_2` to `ReadBinaryFile()` and allocating with `p_2 = malloc(sizeof(Tcars) * (*pc));` each time. Why?

Each call to `malloc()` returns a new block of memory with a new and different address. You overwrite the address of `p_2` with each new call, creating a memory leak and losing the data stored prior to the last call. Instead, you need to `realloc()` to reallocate a larger block of memory and copy your existing data to the new larger block so you can add the next `Tcars` worth of data at the end of the reallocated block.

If you are reading data from one file, then there is no need to pass `p_2` as a parameter to begin with. Simply declare a new pointer in `ReadBinaryFile()` and `realloc()` and add each `Tcars` worth of data at the end and then return the newly allocated pointer. (you must validate every allocation and reallocation)

Your choice of `void` for `WriteBinaryFile()` will conceal any error encountered creating or writing to your new file. You must validate EVERY input/output file operation, especially if the data written will be used later in your program. A simple choice of return of type `int` returning `0` for failure and `1` for success (or vice-versa, up to you) is all you need. That way you can handle any error during file creation or writing and not blindly assume success.

A slightly more subtle issue/error is your allocation for `ParkingLot1` using `malloc()`. Ideally you would use `calloc()` or use `memset` to set all bytes zero. Why? You write the entire `Tcars` struct to the file. `malloc()` does not initialize the memory allocated. That means all characters in the `company` name between the end of the name (the nul-terminating character) and the end of the `16` bytes of storage will be uninitialized. While that will not cause problems with your read or write, it is far better to ensure all data being written to your file is initialized data. Otherwise examining the contents of the file will show blocks of uninitialized values written to the file.

Another small style issue is the `'*'` in the declaration of a pointer generally goes with the variable and not the type. Why?

```c
    Tcars* a, b, c;
```

The declaration above most certainly does not declare 3-pointers of type `Tcars`, instead it declares pointer `a` and two struct of type `Tcars` with automatic storage duration `b`, and `c`. Writing:

```c
    Tcars *a, b, c;
```

makes that clear.

Lastly, don't use *MagicNumbers* or hardcode filenames in your functions. You shouldn't need to recompile your code just to read or write a different filename. It's fine to use `"cars.dat"` as a default filename in `main()`, but either take the filenames as the 1st argument to your program (that's what `int argc, char **argv` parameters to `main()` are for) or prompt the user for a filename and take it as input. `3` and `16` are *MagicNumbers*. If you need a constant, `#define` them or use a global `enum`.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to the following to read an unknown number of `Tcars` from your data file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NCARS 3       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COMPANY 16

typedef struct Cars {
    int years;
    char company[COMPANY];
} Tcars;

/* returns 1 on success 0 on error */
int WriteBinaryFile (char *file_name, Tcars *p_1, size_t nelem)
{
  FILE *f;
  size_t size = sizeof *p_1;
  
  f = fopen (file_name, "wb");
  if (!f) {   /* validate file open for writing */
    perror ("fopen-file_name-write");
    return 0;
  }
  
  /* validate that nelem blocks of size are written to file */
  if (fwrite (p_1, size, nelem, f) != nelem) {
    return 0;
  }
  
  if (fclose (f)) {       /* validate close-after-write */
    perror ("fclose-f");
    return 0;
  }
  
  return 1;
}

/* returns pointer to allocated block holding ncars cars on success,
 * NULL on failure to read any cars from file_name.
 */
Tcars *ReadBinaryFile (char *file_name, size_t *ncars)
{
  FILE *f;
  
  Tcars *tcars = NULL, temp;
  size_t nelem = *ncars, size = sizeof (Tcars);
  
  f = fopen (file_name, "rb");
  if (!f) {
    perror ("fopen-file_name-read");
    return NULL;
  }
  
  while (fread (&temp, size, 1, f) == 1) {
    /* always realloc to a temporary pointer */
    void *tempptr = realloc (tcars, (nelem + 1) * size);
    if (!tempptr) {   /* validate realloc succeeds or handle error */
      perror ("realloc-tcars");
      break;
    }
    tcars = tempptr;                      /* assign reallocated block */
    memcpy (tcars + nelem, &temp, size);  /* copy new car to end of block */
    nelem += 1;
  }
  
  fclose (f);
  *ncars = nelem;
  
  return tcars;
}

/* void is fine for print functions with no bearing on the 
 * continued operation of your code.
 */
void prn_cars (Tcars *cars, size_t nelem)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nelem; i++) {
    printf ("%4d  %s\n", cars[i].years, cars[i].company);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* read from filename provided as 1st argument ("cars.dat" by default) */
  char *filename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "cars.dat";
  /* must use calloc() on ParkingLot1 or zero memory to avoid writing
   * unintialized characters (rest of company) to file.
   */
  Tcars *ParkingLot1 = calloc (NCARS, sizeof(Tcars)),
        *ParkingLot2 = NULL;
  size_t cars_amount = 0;
  
  if (!ParkingLot1) {   /* validate EVERY allocation */
    perror ("calloc-ParkingLot1");
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < NCARS; i++) {
    ParkingLot1[i].years = 2000 + i;
  }
  
  strcpy (ParkingLot1[0].company, "Fiat");
  strcpy (ParkingLot1[1].company, "Ford");
  strcpy (ParkingLot1[2].company,"Toyota");
  
  /* validate WriteBinaryFile succeeds or handle error */
  if (!WriteBinaryFile (filename, ParkingLot1, NCARS)) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  ParkingLot2 = ReadBinaryFile (filename, &cars_amount);
  
  if (ParkingLot2) {  /* validate ReadBinaryFile succeeds or handle error */
    prn_cars (ParkingLot2, cars_amount);    /* output cars read from file */
    free (ParkingLot2);                     /* free if ParkingLot2 not NULL */
  }
  
  free(ParkingLot1);  /* free ParkingLot1 */
}
```

(**note:** you always check the return of `fclose()` after-a-write to catch any file errors and error flushing the data to the file that can't be caught at the time of the `fwrite()` call)

Also note in the man page for `fread` and `fwrite` they can read or write less than the number of byte (or elements) you request. A *short-read* may or may not represent an error or premature end-of-file and you need to call `ferror()` and `feof()` to determine which, if any, occurred. While direct file reads from disk are not as prone to *short-reads* as network reads and writes, a full implementation would protect against a short-read regardless of where the data is being read from or written to. Further investigation is left to you.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./fwrite_fread_cars dat/cars.dat
2000  Fiat
2001  Ford
2002  Toyota
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./fwrite_fread_cars dat/cars.dat
==7237== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7237== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7237== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7237== Command: ./fwrite_fread_cars dat/cars.dat
==7237==
2000  Fiat
2001  Ford
2002  Toyota
==7237==
==7237== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7237==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7237==   total heap usage: 9 allocs, 9 frees, 10,340 bytes allocated
==7237==
==7237== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7237==
==7237== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==7237== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have any question.